# Facebook Checkbox Plugin on API.AI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

We are using API.AI and we want to implement the Facebook Checkbox Plugin of Facebook to connect the bot with users.

[image]

If I clearly understand how it works, Facebook will send a event when a user validate a form that contains this checkbox.

Is it possible to get the event without modifiying the heroku app between Facebook and API.AI ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this as well.  From what I can find API.AI does not support any messenger webhook events other than "messages" and "messaging_postbacks."  You need "messaging_optins" in order to receive these events.

While you can't receive these events through API.AI, I did find a workaround that allows you to keep your current configuration between api.ai and facebook.

Rather than worrying about receiving the opt-in event from facebook, just trigger the facebook send API shortly after confirming the opt-in.

This works because you are the one to set the "user_ref" parameter, so as long as the user was logged into facebook and the checkbox was checked, triggering the confirmation will store the user_ref in facebook's system, and you can call Facebook's API with the same parameter right afterwards to initiate a conversation with the user.

Here's an example of the entire flow:

Javascript and HTML front end.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : '<APP_ID>',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.6'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
);

function confirmOptIn() {
    FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
        'app_id':'<APP_ID>',
        'page_id':'<PAGE_ID>',
        'ref':"<OPTIONAL_REF>",
        'user_ref':'<UNIQUE_USER_REF>'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Send an AJAX call here with the user_ref param to a script that will call the facebook send API.
        // Short delay to give facebook time to log the unique_user_ref
    }, 1000);
}
</script>

<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"  
    origin="<YOUR_SITE_URL>"
    page_id=<PAGE_ID>
    messenger_app_id=<APP_ID>
    user_ref="<UNIQUE_USER_REF>"
    prechecked="true" 
    allow_login="true" 
    size="large">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="confirmOptIn()" value="Confirm Opt-in"/>
```

Here's an example of server side code to call the send-api using PHP

```
<?php
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>";

    $data = [
        'recipient' => [
            'user_ref' => <UNIQUE_USER_REF>
        ],
        'message' => [
            'text' => 'Hello world!'
        ]
    ];

    $post_data = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_export($response);
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this very good idea ! :) I've already re-implemented the connection between facebook and API.AI to handle this event but for a future bot I will certainly use your solution wich is a lot more simple ^^